# Accessing a nested element 3 levels deep using page objects

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem, pageobjects

Using the Page Object model and gem I want to access an element that is nested 3 layers deep. I've successfully accessed nested elements that are 2 elements deep but for 3 the same method isn't working.

3 elements defined in my Page Object:

```
div(:serv_info, :class => "service-info")
div(:validate_method, :class => "validate-method")
div(:scar_input_group, :class => "input-group")
```

So I tried to chain those 3 elements to access the `div` `class` `input-container input-left-half round` like this:

```
div(:scar_first_name_error){validate_method_element.serv_info_element.scar_input_group_element.div_element(:class => "input-container input-left-half round")}
```

But I got the error that `serv_info_element` is an undefined method, which makes sense, but is it possible to chain the 3 predefined elements I stated above to access the `input-container input-left-half round`?

I read this: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Nested-Elements but didn't want to have to repeat any code if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the nesting is always the same, rather than having the `:scar_first_name_error` map through each ancestor, you could define each element with respect to its parent (or ancestor).

Let us assume the HTML is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="validate-method">
      <div class="service-info">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-container input-left-half round">
            text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could define the page as:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  div(:serv_info) { validate_method_element.div_element(:class => "service-info") }
  div(:validate_method, :class => "validate-method")
  div(:scar_input_group) { serv_info_element.div_element(:class => "input-group") }
  div(:scar_first_name_error) { scar_input_group_element.div_element(:class => "input-container input-left-half round") }
end
```

Notice that the `:serv_info` is defined with respect to its parent `:validate_method`, `:scar_input_group` is defined with respect ot its parent `:serv_info`, etc.

With this page object, we can see we can get the lower element's text:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
p page.scar_first_name_error
#=> "text"
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, will try this out and see if it works.